# How to fix 'Cannot Resolve Symbol 'v7' error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use the android support recyclerView widget, and though I've added all the dependencies to my build.gradle file (I think), the line "import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;" in my activity isn't resolving. I'm new to Android Studio, so I might be missing something very basic.

So far I've tried adding the google repository in allprojects of the project build gradle, as well as that of my module build gradle. I've also shifted around my dependencies and tried changing version numbers. And I tried invalidating caches and restarting. I do seem to be able to import "import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;", but that isn't the same from what I've heard.

This is my build gradle file:

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chaos"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        customDebugType {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1'

   // implementation 'com.android.support:support-v7'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation ('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha02', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
}
```

And then this is the import I'm attempting in my main activity. It seems I can import android.support.v4 libraries, but v7 isn't even an auto-complete option. I'd appreciate the help!

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
```

I expect the import line to resolve, as it currently doesn't.

Comment: There are a couple of things you should check, did the grafle build sync? And mostly, you cant combine androidx with support, you have to choose

Comment: as cutiko said, this could the android x issue. Refactor to AndroidX again, if the issue is still there, invalidate cache.

Comment: Is there way to take back my use of AndroidX? The gradle build is indeed synced :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Android X, try this dependency instead

`implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'`

Comment: Is there a way I can choose not to use AndroidX anymore? Or is that a bad idea?

Comment: When creating the project you can uncheck AndroidX option. However, i do not recommend doing that. The old support libraries will no longer be updated. Only AndroidX from now on.